# trying to match records from 2 different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables (2008 mssql database), lets say `x.dbo` and `y.dbo`

`x.dbo` has a field name called `"customer name"` and `y.dbo` has a field name called `"customers"`. One table's data is entered by `customers` and the other's one data is entered by the `shipping company` and what I have been trying to accomplish for months is filtering the `customers` that match all and that match partially..(2 of the conditions together)

So here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM X JOIN Y ON 
UPPER(X.CustomerName) LIKE '%' + UPPER(Y.Customers)    + '%' 
OR    UPPER(Y.Customers)    LIKE '%' + UPPER(X.CustomerName) + '%';`
```

The above query gives most of the matching records but not all of them.

I have no idea why this code above does not match these 2 names below:

```
 İBRAHİM HAKKI KAZANCI <--> İBRAHIM HAKKI KAZANCI
```

the only difference between these 2 names are one is written `"İBRAHİM"` and the other one is `"İBRAHIM"` (with Upper I) and I need them to match since they are the same (while the shipping company enters the data (based on our invoice), sometimes they do little mistakes like this..)

Note: my database's colation is `Turkish_CI_AS`.

I'd be pleased if you could fix my sql statement so that these 2 names also would match..

Comment: Try using `COLLATE Turkish_CI_AI`, the `_AI` part means that it will use *Accent Insensitive* comparison. You can add this into each part of the `ON`-clause.

Comment: they don't match because they're not the same. They contain different characters. Maybe LIKE doesn't do what you think it does. As Peter says in this specific case you might be able to use a different collation to help.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM X JOIN Y ON
UPPER(X.CustomerName) LIKE '%' + UPPER(Y.Customers)    + '%' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AI
OR    UPPER(Y.Customers)    LIKE '%' + UPPER(X.CustomerName) + '%' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AI;
Thx Peter, Ive tried this above but still not working

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an accurate solution, but can work for you. Use [Soundex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to compare them.

In your case the Soundex function

```
select SOUNDEX('İBRAHİM HAKKI KAZANCI') , SOUNDEX('İBRAHIM HAKKI KAZANCI')
```

and that will generate

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
I165                I165
```

So you can use something like

```
SELECT * FROM X JOIN Y ON 
SOUNDEX(X.CustomerName) = SOUNDEX(Y.Customers) 
OR    SOUNDEX(Y.Customers)=SOUNDEX(X.CustomerName)
```

Comment: do not replace your solution by soundex solution only add it as another `or`

Comment: Thats correct. It will give strength to the priveous query. @Livius